# Is the two sample z-test a Wald or Score test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, likelihood-ratio, z-test

I saw the R prop.test returns the Chi square p-value, and it got me thinking this:
Is the z-test with pooled standard error corresponding to score test, and the one with unpooled SE corresponding to Wald test?